# Ruby Can't Convert Array to Integer in For Loop

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to get an array of hashes (called hashes) which I will proceed to fill with booleans based on whether or not a word in a line of input is in some arrays. To put this into perspective, I'm taking a line of input, and scanning it to see if the words in that input are inside a series of arrays I have set up.

```
11: for i in words
12:    if nouns.include?(words[i])
13:        hashes[i][:nouns] = true
14:    end 
15:
16:    if adjectives.include?(words[i])
17:        hashes[i][:adjectives] = true
18:    end 
19: end
```

This errors on line 12, saying Analyzer.rb:12 in `[]': can't convert Array into Integer (TypeError)

I get the feeling I've just made a silly formatting error somewhere, but I can't see it. Any Suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the content of `words`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
11: for word in words
12:    if nouns.include?(word)
13:        hashes[word][:nouns] = true
14:    end 
15:
16:    if adjectives.include?(word)
17:        hashes[word][:adjectives] = true
18:    end 
19: end
```

`word`, that was `i` before (I gave it a better name), is actually already an element of the array, not an index.

Comment: In your answer you try to access the hashes array with the object word by it's `[]` method. This should only work if word is an integer, but should fail if it's a String (or anything else). Why does this work perfectly? Looks like a flawed answer to me.

Answer (score 2):

You should try using rubys powerful enumerable style of coding to avoid such errors. For loops are not ruby like.

Your code could be written as:

```
11: words.each_with_index do |word, i|
12:    
13:    hashes[i][:nouns] = true if nouns.include?(word)   
14:    hashes[i][:adjectives] = true if adjectives.include?(word)
15:
16: end
```

Comment: There is no index in OP's code, only a badly named variable i.

Comment: he said it's an array of hashes called "hashes". So he wanted to access the array by index?
It confues me that Nicola Miotto's answer works perfectly, as arrays `[]` method requires an index or a range, not an object. If word is a string it would work if hashes is a `Hash` not a `Array`

Answer (score 0):

Better to use methdo **each_index** for your array.
But if you want to use **for** for array try to change word[i] to word. **for** operate with object but not with index.
Nicola Miotto wrote code for your example.